# What makes many water soluble fertilizers blue?

Tags: synthesis, color

I've noticed that water soluble fertilizers tend to be blue. What chemicals or chemical reactions cause this color here? Is this necessary or for aesthetic purposes? I haven't seen this in organic fertilizers. I figured chemists might be able to examine the ingredients of Miracle Gro or something and tell me. I'm guessing it has something to do with copper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What chemicals or chemical reactions cause this color here? Is this necessary or for aesthetic purposes?

I have some Miracle Gro on hand, the water soluble kind: The blue stuff is copper sulfate, or ${\rm CuSO}_{4}$. [Here](http://eldoradochemical.com/MSDS_Sheets/EDC/Third_Party_Products/MIRACLE_GRO_ALL_PURPOSE_PLANT_FOOD_24-8-16.pdf) is the MSDS for Miracle Gro Water Soluble All Purpose Plant Food, which lists the chemicals in the mixture.

> Is this necessary or for aesthetic purposes?

It's necessary in these formulations for purposes detailed (in part) [here](http://www.extension.umn.edu/agriculture/nutrient-management/micronutrients/copper-for-crop-production/) and [here](http://npic.orst.edu/factsheets/cuso4gen.html). In short, it is included in these formulations because plants need copper for biosynthesis; and because it acts as a fungicide, presumably leading to a nicer ecosystem in one's lawn/garden.